# Missing something basic with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm working my way though Catalin Tudose's "Java Persistence with Spring Data and Hibernate" and I've hit a roadblock with the Spring Data JPA example in Chapter 2.

Complete code is here:

[Example Code](https://github.com/ctudose/java-persistence-spring-data-hibernate)

If I use the example exactly as written using @Test like this it works fine:

```
package com.manning.javapersistence.ch02;

import com.manning.javapersistence.ch02.configuration.SpringDataConfiguration;
import com.manning.javapersistence.ch02.repositories.MessageRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringDataConfiguration.class})
public class HelloWorldSpringDataJPATest {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Test
    public void storeLoadMessage() {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setText("Hello World from Spring Data JPA!");

        messageRepository.save(message);

        List<Message> messages = (List<Message>) messageRepository.findAll();

        assertAll(
                () -> assertEquals(1, messages.size()),
                () -> assertEquals("Hello World from Spring Data JPA!", messages.get(0).getText())
        );

    }
}
```

I believe that the line:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringDataConfiguration.class})
```

sets up the context so that my SpringDataConfiguration gets processed by Spring Data JPA and the @AutoWired works at runtime.

But I am wanting to use this outside of the test context and I have this:

```
public class App {

    @Autowired  private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    public void saveMessage(Message message) {      messageRepository.save(message);        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        App app = new App();

        Message message = new Message();        
        String timeStamp = new 
        SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());       
        message.setText("SpringDataJPA: " + timeStamp);          
        app.saveMessage(message);

    }    }
```

When I run it I get a NullPointerException because the messageRepository is not getting auto wired by Spring Data JPA.

What am I missing?  How do I get the @AutoWired to work at runtime outside of the @Test context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the test case , the spring testing framework which is enabled by `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` which will help you to configure and start the spring context behind the scene and so those `@Autowired` stuff can work.

To do the equivalent things in a standalone and non spring-boot way,  you can create `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` manually like :

```java
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringDataConfiguration.class, App.class);
         App app = context.getBean(App.class);
         app.main();
    }
}
```

And you also need to modify the `main()` of the `App` class a bit :

```
public class App {

    @Autowired 
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    public void saveMessage(Message message) {      
     messageRepository.save(message);        
    }


    public void main() {       
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Message message = new Message();            
        message.setText("some text");          
        saveMessage(message);
     }
}
```

mainly you have to change it to the instance method because you do not need create the `App` instance by yourself but let spring to create and then manage it such that it can autowire other beans like `MessageRepository` into it.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!  What I was missing in my understanding was how to get the ApplicationContext here.  Your simple answer was very helpful!

Comment: good to hear. consider to accept my answer if you find it is helpful to you. cheers

Answer (score -1):

In your App class, Spring will not automatically inject application context . You need to manually inject the Spring application context and retrieve MessageRepository Bean from the Spring application context .

You can use something like this.

```html
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    private MessageRepository messageRepository ; 

    public void saveMessage(Message message) {messageRepository.save(message);}

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
      System.out.println("Hello World!");
      
      // Initialize Spring application context
      ApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
      // Retrieve MessageRepository Bean
       messageRepository = app.getBean(MessageRepository.class);
      
        App app = new App();
        Message message = new Message();        
        String timeStamp = new 
        SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new java.util.Date());       
        message.setText("SpringDataJPA: " + timeStamp);          
        app.saveMessage(message);

    } 
    
 }
```

Comment: he is not using spring-boot , just the plain spring. Also the `App` need to be defined as the spring bean but not create it by yourself , otherwise `MessageRepository` cannot be auto-wired into it. see my answers to see what i mean. cheers

Comment: As noted, not using Spring Boot here.